# Parsing and finding matches across a data frame

Tags: r

I have a large data frame with these variable

```
ID    ModelA                    Target Model
1     Striker                   Striker
2     (YZ123)(Y234)             YZ123
3     Boxer                     boxer
4     (Y456)(Y122)(Y444)        (Y456)
```

I need to create a new column which matches ModelA and Target Model.

```
ID    ModelA                    Target Model         Match
1     Striker                   Striker              Striker
2     (YZ123)(Y234)             YZ123                YZ123
3     Boxer                     boxer                Boxer
4     (Y456)(Y122)(Y444)        (Y456)               Y456
```

Comment: Cool.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

We create a string pattern by `paste`ing the elements of third column after removing the parentheses using `gsub`.  This can be used for extracting the words from the second column.

```
library(stringr)
pat <- sprintf('(?i)(%s)',paste(gsub('[[:punct:]]+', '', df1[,3]), collapse='|'))
df1$Match <- str_extract(df1[,2], pat)
df1
#  ID             ModelA Target_Model   Match
#1  1            Striker      Striker Striker
#2  2      (YZ123)(Y234)        YZ123   YZ123
#3  3              Boxer        boxer   Boxer
#4  4 (Y456)(Y122)(Y444)       (Y456)    Y456
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:4, ModelA = c("Striker", "(YZ123)(Y234)", 
"Boxer", "(Y456)(Y122)(Y444)"), Target_Model = c("Striker", "YZ123", 
"boxer", "(Y456)")), .Names = c("ID", "ModelA", "Target_Model"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Answering `canihaztehcodez` questions just encourages them, and such answers very rarely provide any value to anyone but the question's creator.